# Windows Service denied access to network share despite being in correct AD group

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group

Scenario:

- I have a Windows service written in C# that runs on SERVER1 as domain user **mydomain\serviceacct**.
- The user **mydomain\serviceacct** is a member of the AD Security Group **MySharedFolderAccess**
- The AD group **MySharedFolderAccess** has read/write privileges on the shared network path **\SERVER2\data** (and all data in sub-folders)
- The share has granted read/write access to "Everyone"
- The service is still getting access denied to the network share

Some more background:

- The service in question used to run under an account that had domain admin privileges (this is what I am trying to fix). Unsurprisingly, it worked fine.
- The service account was added to the **MySharedFolderAccess** group after we setup the service login details (although the machine has been rebooted since). At first, I thought it was an AD propagation problem, but this has been going on for several days now.
- We have never logged into a machine using the service account (not sure that is relevant

I could grant the service user **mydomain\serviceacct**, direct read/write privileges to the shared folder. The trouble is that the folder in question is massive and recursively setting access to a single user takes hours - I can't even guarantee it will work.

I am not the author of the C# code, but will be happy to pass along any suggestions that might involve a code change.

Comment: Do you have logon auditting enabled on the (file) server? If you do, the security event log will show whether your service account is successfully logging on or not (ie. is this an authentication or a authorisation issues).

Comment: Thanks Richard. I do have login auditing enabled, but I am not seeing anything remotely useful in the event logs

Comment: In that case I would look at whether Server1 is having some kind of AD issue or routing (albeit I wouldn't expect access denied for the latter).